# не правильно отображается js код в браузере

Tags: javascript, html

Пишу код js и сохраняю в формате html - работает.
Пишу новый файл с вызовом того файла в формате html - не работает.

Пробовал сохранять и открывать 1 файл в формате js - не работает и отображает код файла. Я только-только начал изучать js, но понимаю что вопрос идиотский :)

<sub>1 файл</sub>

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            alert( 'Я - JavaScript!' );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

<sub>2 файл</sub>

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="js.html"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: как идет попытка вызова второго файла?

Comment: двойной клик по файлу

Comment: _Пишу новый файл с вызовом того файла_ - как в новом файле вызывается _тот_ файл?

Comment: <html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <script src="js.html"></script>

</body>

</html>

Comment: всю необходимую информацию надо добавлять непосредственно в вопрос. Под вопросом есть кнопка "править" нажав которую можно отредактировать свой вопрос. Добавь содержимое обоих файлов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Основная ошибка в том, что файл, который подключается через тег *script* должен содержать *только* яваскрипт.

Так как в первом файле кроме скрипта еще и *html* - он не работает.

Для того чтобы заработало, необходимо удалить весь ненужный html, останется только следующее:

```
alert( 'Я - JavaScript!' );
```

Для полноты картины можно переименовать файлик в *"js.js"* и в итоге получить

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="js.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

При этом, так как в первом файле остался *только* яваскрипт, то при открытии его просто как файла, будет выведен текст файла, и так как в нем нет *html*, будет выведен текст скрипта.